# FTP server for LAN-only use-- Write-permission issue in /var/www/

Tags: ftp

I'm trying to setup an FTP server so that any machine on the network can upload files to my /var/www/  on my Ubuntu 13.04 LAMP server -- with or without authentication.

I've spent most of the day trying to achieve this, to no resolve. I am ready for a fresh approach...

I've tried using vsftpd and proftpd + gadmin-proftpd  -- details, below..

But the issue seems to be that I cannot find a way to get write privileges on /var/www/ via a remote computer. 
I can ssh in, but when accessing files via nautilus, sftp://[server.ip] - I cannot copy --

---

The following may be irrelevant: 
vsftpd.conf has all the things it should - anon_enable and the like, but I can not write files to the server from the client.

proftpd does similar, although I set up an ftpuser + password which it does not accept. 
In spite of passing the connection test, the client machine still cannot write to the server's /var/www/

SO - since all I am looking to do is use this as a LAN-Only FTP -- perhaps there is another solution that I have not come across, yet.

I've tried some odd dozen tutorials on both vsftpd and proftpd to no avail--

Any advice on this matter would be highly appreciated.

Comment: If you have iptables enabled you would need the IPTABLES_MODULES="ip_conntrack_ftp"

Comment: Thanks- I did, at one point, try $ modprobe ip_conntrack_ftp -  
However, I don't believe a firewall is the issue, as opening a browser to "ftp://[server's-ip]" -- accepts the server's sudo-username and password --

Answer (score 0):

I  solved this with the following:

1. Abandon all ftp server programs--- openssh-server includes sftp
2. Add authorized user, make sure mode and ownership is correct:

   ## useradd -G www-data ftpuser

   ## chmod 775 /var/www/

   ## chown -R ftpuser /var/www/
3. sftp ftpuser@server